# SQL count char except when it's enclosed

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

In Oracle SQL I want to count all commas in one string excluding those that are inside double quotes.

In the next example the count must be `3`:

```
'string1,string2,"string,3",string4'
```

In the next example the count must be also `3`:

```
'string1,string2,"string,3","string,4"'
```

`REGEXP_COUNT(my_string, ',')` returns `4` and `5` respectively, this was my best attempt but it returns `1` always:

```
SELECT  REGEXP_COUNT(my_string, ',*^(.*".*".*),*')
FROM    (
    SELECT  'string1,string2,"string,3",string4' AS my_string
    FROM    DUAL);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove the offending string and then do the count

**[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/6846)**

```
SELECT REGEXP_COUNT(
                  REGEXP_REPLACE(my_string, '(\"[^\"]*\")', ''),
                  ',')
FROM    (
    SELECT  'string1,string2,"string,3",string4' AS my_string
    FROM    DUAL);
```

Comment: seems to work but I added another example where it fails. Looks like it first searches for all the matches and then removes them, instead of removing them when it finds them. This is causing it to use the quotes twice for different commas. In the last example is throwing `2` instead of `3`.

Comment: Yes, im begginner on regexp. But the idea stand. Search duplicated and replace it before count. Im still looking a regex to work

Comment: Try `REGEXP_REPLACE(my_string, '(\"[^\"]*\")', ''),`

Comment: @stribizhev Can you explain it for me? `()` is a group. Start with double quoute `\"` then  `[^\"]*` this part lose me because I tought should be anything ending with quote.

Comment: The regex matches `"`, then `[^"]*` matches 0 or more characters other than `"`, and again a `"`. I suppose `'"[^"]*"'` should work the same here.